# Need to Backup from multiple sources

Tags: web, cron, backup

I am using the script below to do daily backups. I need to add more folders to be included in the daily backup, and I would like to have them contained in the same zip file. How would this scripted be modified to backup multiple folders to the same compressed file?

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`                        # This Command will read the date.
FILENAME=backup-xmltv-www-$TIME.tar.gz       # The filename including the date.
SRCDIR=/var/www/html/wp-admin                # Source backup folder.
DESDIR=/var/backups                          # Destination of backup file.
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

I have tried to add multiple source directories to the script, but only the last source in the list gets compressed.

```
SRCDIR=/var/www/html/wp-admin
SRCDIR=/var/www/html/wp-content
SRCDIR=/var/www/html/wp-includes
```

I have also tried to give the sources different numbers, but tar errors out to tell me to look at the tar help file.

```
SRCDIR1=/var/www/html/wp-admin
SRCDIR2=/var/www/html/wp-content
SRCDIR3=/var/www/html/wp-includes
```

Comment: Your first attempt didn't work because you're redefining the value of SRCDIR every subsequent time you assign it, so yes when everything is said and done the last assignment will be the value you have. Your second attempt didn't work probably because you never adjusted the tar command, so you're still looking for $SRCDIR which no longer existed. Bigger question is why are you not using logrotate for this, as this is exactly what it is designed to do?

Comment: Your right. The second method would of worked if I would of adjusted the tar command..............................


`tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $1SRCDIR  $2SRCDIR $3SRCDIR` and so on. Thank alot for pointing that out, as I will go back and use method #2 as it's a lot cleaner and looks better.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to work for multiple directories....

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`                      # This Command will read the date.
FILENAME=backup-xmltv-www-$TIME.tar.gz     # The filename including the date.
DESDIR=/var/backups                        # Destination of backup file.
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME /var/www/html/wp-admin /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-includes /var/www/html/*.php /var/www/html/*.html
```